How to render .glb files with image textures in React Native (Expo)?
I am developing a React Native app using Expo and want to render .glb files with image textures. However, I'm not sure if this is supported in Expo, and I couldn't find clear documentation on this.
I've tried using libraries like expo-three and react-three-fiber, but I haven't been able to load textures from .glb files properly.
Is there a supported way to achieve this in Expo? If not, are there any workarounds, or do I need to eject from Expo to use a native module?
An example of someone who has done this or a sample project would be nice.
Any guidance or examples would be appreciated!

Use native module , huge documentation and example,
